# "I will refuse nothing to a soul that makes a request of me in virtue of my passion" - meaning?

Tags: meaning, phrases

"I will refuse nothing to a soul that makes a request of me in virtue of my passion"

I am having trouble understanding this sentence because of the statement "in virtue of my passion" that follows immediately after "....request of me".(English is my second language). Could someone re-phrase the above sentence into an easier form to understand?

More specifically, is it 
"I will refuse nothing to the soul that makes a request of (me in virtue of my passion)", or

"I will refuse nothing to the soul that makes a request of me,(in virtue of my passion)"?

Thank you