# Are these two statements equivalent?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning

Statement i:

> I will refuse nothing to a soul that makes a request of me in virtue of my passion. In this hour you can obtain everything for yourself and for others for asking - statement (i)

I tried to re-phrase the above statement as shown below.

Statement ii:

> If someone makes a request to me, for the sake of my passion, I won't refuse their request. In this hour you will obtain everything that you are asking for
>   - statement (ii)

Are the statements (i) and (ii) equivalent?

If you are curious about where the statement (i) is from,
see [The Hour of Great Mercy –
The Divine Mercy Message from the Marians of the Immaculate Conception](http://thedivinemercy.org/message/devotions/hour.php).

Comment: Context!  We need context!  The statement is obviously archaic and/or poetic, so we need to know who's speaking and what the general topic is.

Comment: http://thedivinemercy.org/message/devotions/hour.php  -- "Me" is Jesus, and "Passion" refers to his suffering and dying.

Comment: This looks a awful lot like a duplicate of your [earlier question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/238897/70861).  As with that one you should have included the context, so that people know that "me" is Jesus and "passion" means Jesus's crucifixion.

Comment: @J.Taylor: You should be aware that two edits have been made to this question to repair damage done by your edit: you deleted words that shouldn’t have been deleted, and you broke the link. Please be more careful.

Comment: @Scott , yes, I see, I was editing the first edit. That was not being careful.

Answer (score 0):

It's old-fashioned if not outright archaic usage, and would be unfamiliar to most native speakers:

> *virtue*: Phrases
>
> by (or in) virtue of
>
> **Because or as a result of:**

*[virtue](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/virtue)*, Oxford Dictionaries. Oxford University Press, n.d. Web. 12 April 2015.

The full quote is:

> At three o’clock, implore My mercy, especially for sinners; and, if only for a brief moment, immerse yourself in My Passion, particularly in My abandonment at the moment of agony. This is the hour of great mercy… In this hour, I will refuse nothing to the soul that makes a request of Me in virtue of My Passion.

[Diary: Divine Mercy in My Soul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diary:_Divine_Mercy_in_My_Soul), [Faustina Kowalska](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faustina_Kowalska)

To make sense of it you also need to know that 'passion' is being used in a special sense:

> (the Passion)
>
> **The suffering and death of Jesus**

*[passion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/passion)*, Oxford Dictionaries. Oxford University Press, n.d. Web. 12 April 2015.

So Kowalska writes that Jesus said to her (speaking in rather archaic language) something like this:

"At three o'clock, if someone makes a request to me where they give my suffering and death as the reason that I should grant their request, I won't refuse them".

An alternative interpretation could be:

"At three o'clock, if someone makes a request to me, I won't refuse their request, because of my suffering and death".

Kowalska's native language was definitely Polish; I'm not clear whether Kowalska wrote her diary in English or Polish; even if she wrote it in English, I'm not clear whether she's writing that Jesus spoke to her in English, or whether she's writing that he spoke to her in Polish and she's translated it to English. So translation may be an issue here. Anyway, it's a very formal and old-fashioned tone.

Comment: It cannot be that old. Kowalska was born in the 20th century, 1905 to be precise. My sense is that it has been translated from Polish and as a result is a little bit ham-fisted. But the gist of the message is there.

Comment: Hi @WS2, I'm not meaning to suggest that it actually *is* old. I'm saying that the person who wrote or spoke it has chosen to use a tone which is very formal and very old-fashioned. I'm choosing not to speculate as to why either Jesus, Kowalska or Kowalska's translator would speak or write in a tone so very reminiscent of the [King James](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version) translation of the Bible into English.

Comment: @A.E. A clumsy attempt at a translation from Polish into 17th-century English?

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

**In virtue of**: 
through the force of; by authority of.

It doesn't rhyme/fit with "for the sake of my passion"

[**for someone's sake**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for+the+sake) in someone's interests, to someone's advantage, on someone's account, for the benefit of, for the good of, for the welfare of, out of respect for, out of consideration for, out of regard for *I trust you to do a good job for Stan's sake.*

Now,

obtain something for asking = the only thing you have to do obtain that something is to ask

which doesn't match your "you will obtain everything that you are asking for."

What is the purpose of this exercise? The original is consecrated by tradition.